# More views than people in Telegram

Tags: security, telegram-messenger

I have a private channel in the `Telegram` where there were always 4 people, I did not kick anyone and did not invite new ones. And at one point I began to notice that there are more views on messages than people in the channel. Views reached 7, it scared me a little.

[image]

What this can mean and was it worth it for me to worry about this? (I started to worry about this, because this channel is sent confidential information between employees at work)

Comment: Could be that a single person with multiple clients all acknowledge the view? So one "view" for phone client, another for web, another for a different phone or tablet and so on? You could probably test this yourself by watching on another device and seeing if a new client increments the counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telegram is funny in that views can accumulate and a person can count for more than once.

Old views are still counted for hours afterward.
Whenever you open the channel and see the files, the views number will be
updated by one.
Forwarded copies of your messages are also counted as views.

In short, don't worry - the views number is just inconsistent.
It doesn't mean the number of currently viewing persons.

Answer (score 2):

Telegram channel views don't show the number of accounts that have viewed that post, and also don't show how many times people opened the channel and saw that post. I think it is not reliable at all. But maybe we can say it depends on the number of IP addresses that have viewed that post, as you change the network you are connected to, and open a channel again, the views of recent posts may increase by one. But i'm not sure about it. You can be sure the number of views on a post is always a good approximation to the real views, mostly more than it, but never exactly reliable.